# Format HTML in Scriban

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-sxa, scriban

using scriban with SXA we notice the generated HTML has a lot of white spaces ex :

```html
<div id=”dv1”>


           <div id=”dv2”>
```

This is because in scriban we have if condition before rendering  the div with id=de2 , is there a way to format the html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful if you posted the Scriban snippet you are using.  I suspect you need to use `~` operator at the end of your `if` code block as described [here](https://github.com/scriban/scriban/blob/master/doc/language.md#14-whitespace-control)

For example:

```
<div 1>


{{- #eat all whitespace to left including newlines
    if true
    #eat whitespace but not newlines to right  ~}}

    <div 2>
{{end}}
```

outputs

```
<div 1>
    <div 2>
```

You can use [this](https://github.com/NeilMacMullen/Textrude) tool to experiment with formatting.